# Dataframe increase speed of for loop for set value of column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe from pandas (import pandas as pd)

```
print(df)
        C1  C2
    0    0   0
    1    0   0
    2    1   0
    3    1   1
    4    1   1
    5    0   1
    6    0   0
    7    0   0
    8    0   0
    9    1   0
    10   1   1
    11   1   1
    12   0   1
    13   0   0
```

I want count +1 in 'C3' after rising edges (rising edges start when C1 =1 and C2=0)
I tried with iterrow()

```
count=1
df['C3'] = 0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if (row.C1 == 1) and (row.C2 == 0):
               count += 1 
               df.at[index, 'C3'] = count
        else:
               df.at[index, 'C3'] = count

    print(df)
         C1  C2  C3
    0    0   0   1
    1    0   0   1
    2    1   0   2
    3    1   1   2
    4    1   1   2
    5    0   1   2
    6    0   0   2
    7    0   0   2
    8    0   0   2
    9    1   0   3
    10   1   1   3
    11   1   1   3
    12   0   1   3
    13   0   0   3
```

for a dataframe with 300000 row, it's little bit slow, does it have a simple way to make it more faster?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @AMC a minimum example exists in the code above

Comment: @anon01 We should be able to copy/paste one or two things and have a running program, that isn't the case here.

Comment: `pd.read_clipboard()` is your friend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

- create a Series `counts` that is a boolean mask for the condition you want (`counts`);
- add `C3` to the original df with value `1 + counts.cumsum()`

Note: pandas joins the series to the dataframe based on index values, *not order*.  Doing some intermediate operation that mangles the series of the df or `counts` will produce unexpected results.

code:

```
counts = (df.C1 == 1) & (df.C2 == 0)
df["C3"] = 1 + counts.cumsum()
```

result:

```
    C1  C2  C3
0    0   0   1
1    0   0   1
2    1   0   2
3    1   1   2
4    1   1   2
5    0   1   2
6    0   0   2
7    0   0   2
8    0   0   2
9    1   0   3
10   1   1   3
11   1   1   3
12   0   1   3
13   0   0   3
```

## Performance

Lets compare the performance of three options: `iterrows`, `df.apply`, and the vectorized solution above:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(C1=np.random.choice(2,size=100000), C2=np.random.choice(2,size=100000)))

df1 = df.copy(deep=True)
df2 = df.copy(deep=True)
df3 = df.copy(deep=True)

def use_iterrows():
    count=1
    df1['C3'] = 0
    for index, row in df1.iterrows():
        if (row.C1 == 1) and (row.C2 == 0):
               count += 1 
               df1.at[index, 'C3'] = count
        else:
               df1.at[index, 'C3'] = count

def use_apply():
    df2['C3'] = df2.apply(lambda x: x['C1']==1 and x['C2']==0, axis=1).cumsum()+1

def use_vectorized():
    counts = (df3.C1 == 1) & (df3.C2 == 0)
    df3["C3"] = 1 + counts.cumsum()

%timeit use_iterrows()
# 8.23 s ± 159 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)    

%timeit use_apply()
# 1.54 s ± 27.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit use_vectorized()
# 1.28 ms ± 66.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Summary: using vectorized functions is by far the fastest (~1000x(!) faster for a df of 100k rows).  I like to keep in the habit of using vectorized solutions when possible.  The strength of `df.apply` is that it is very flexible and will work in situations that are difficult for a vectorized operation.  I don't think I've ever needed iterrows.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

```
df['C3'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['C1']==1 and x['C2']==0, axis=1).cumsum()+1
```

desired result:

```
   C1   C2  C3
0   0   0   1
1   0   0   1
2   1   0   2
3   1   1   2
4   1   1   2
5   0   1   2
6   0   0   2
7   0   0   2
8   0   0   2
9   1   0   3
10  1   1   3
11  1   1   3
12  0   1   3
13  0   0   3
```

**What you need to remember:**

When it comes to long data **do not use iterrows**. It makes it significantly slow.

**apply** -- a much better alternative to iterrows and much more efficient

Comment: Thanks for your solution it's help a lot ! 
Guillaume